# pgfplots' fill between with wrong segment split

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I want the last segment to be white, but it seems that the last segment is
combined with the previous segment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vdw}{0}{\pgfmathparse{8.314*115/(x-0.0000364)-0.1358/x/x}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xlabel      = $V$,
    ylabel      = $P$,
    samples     = 500,
    domain      = 0.00005:0.0005,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 0.00055,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 5*10^6,
  ] 
  \addplot[name path=vdw, black, thick, mark=none, ] {vdw}; 
  \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=1pt] {2.0*10^6}; 
  \addplot fill between[ 
    of = vdw and line, 
    split, % calculate segments
    every segment no 0/.style={white},
    every segment no 1/.style={orange},
    every segment no 2/.style={red},
    every segment no 3/.style={white},
  ];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/139) was fixed in the just released PGFPlots v1.16. Thus, your MWE now works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

To cite from the PGFPLOTS manual (**Sec 5.6.8** Pitfalls and Limitations, p.390),

> The first limitation is scalability. The underlying algorithms are relatively inefficient and scale badly if the number of samples is large. Please apply it to a reasonable sample sizes" and plots with a reasonable number of intersections". That means: if it takes too long, you may need to reduce the sampling density.

So, if you decrease the number of samples a bit (imagine your step with 500 samples, `9x10^{-7}`; too dense), it will give correct results. Here, I have chosen `samples = 200` just by a trial-and-error approach.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vdw}{0}{\pgfmathparse{8.314*115/(x-0.0000364)-0.1358/x/x}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line = left,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xlabel      = $V$,
    ylabel      = $P$,
    samples     = 200,
    domain      = 0.00005:0.0005,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 0.00055,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 5*10^6,
  ] 
  \addplot[name path=vdw, black, thick, mark=none, ] {vdw}; 
  \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=1pt] {2.0*10^6}; 
  \addplot fill between[ 
    of = vdw and line, 
    split, % calculate segments
    every segment no 0/.style={white},
    every segment no 1/.style={orange},
    every segment no 2/.style={red},
    every segment no 3/.style={white},
  ];
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AboAmmar thanks for your analysis. I as package author suppose that despite the paragraph about scalability issues, `pgf`/`pgfplots` should be able to compute the intersection... I have added an item to my todo list.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger Thank you so much. I really enjoy the awesome `pgfplots` package and see its benefits outweigh any limitations. Well done!!